# How do I store an NSMutableArray to Disk on an iPhone app for later retrieval?

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

How do I store an NSMutableArray to Disk on an iPhone app for later retrieval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSArray (as well as other property list objects) provides easy saving/loading to the file - using following methods:

```
+ (id)arrayWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

It might be useful to read [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html) in Apple docs for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Use `[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:myMutableArray toFile:path]`

The folder to store the file at can be determined with:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```